# AnimatedList with FutureBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-animatedlist

I need rebuild my view and trying to use AnimatedList. Container child looks like:

```
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: client.getArticle(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Article>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Article> articles = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: articles.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => formatsRadioList(articles[index], context, _height, onPressing: () {
                _changeHeight();
              }),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
...} else {...}
        },
      ),
```

I'm trying to use AnimatedList but with no success. How to implement AL in this example?

Comment: Are you looking for a general example of `AnimatedList`, or did you run into specific problems when using it?

Comment: FutureBuilder as a child is my specific problem.

Comment: OK, are you familiar with `AnimatedList`? It needs a `global key` on its `state` to do insertion and deletion, right? So in that case, consider not using a `FutureBuilder`, and listen on the future yourself (using methods like `.then()`).